# one-to-one NHibernate mapping

Tags: nhibernate, one-to-one

I've been at this for the last 3 days and still can't figure it out. Conceptually I need to design an envelope object and its to and from addresses (object). I have the following database schema (which I cannot change):

Table Envelope

- EnvelopeId (PK)
- List item
- PostmarkDate

Table Address

- EnvelopeId (PK, FK in Envelope)
- AdressType (1 - for From addresses, 2 - for To addresses)
- Street
- State
- ZipCode

*unique contraint on (EnvelopeId, AdressType)

My classes are as follows:

```
public class Envelope
{
public virtual long EnvelopeId { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime PostmarkDate { get; set; }
public virtual Address FromAddress { get; set; }
public virtual Address ToAddress { get; set; }
}


public class Address
{
public virtual AddressId { get; set; }
public virtual Envelope Envelope { get; set; }
public virtual AdressType { get; set; }
public virtual Street { get; set; }
public virtual State { get; set; }
public virtual ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

So, Envelope ends up having 2 corresponding Address entries (with it's primary key): one with AddressType 1 and one with AddressType 2. I haven't included my mapping files because that's where the problem lies. I attempted several solutions:

1. a one-to-one relationship between Envelope and Address. I had 2 one-to-one tags in the Envelope mapping file, and  a one-to-one tag in the Address mapping file. The Address mapping file also had a foreign generator and a constrained="true" on Envelope. NHibernate complained that the one-to-one mappings between Envelope and Address was confusing.
2. created 2 classes FromAddress and ToAddress, both derived from Address. Envelope class now had a FromAddress and a ToAddress (instead of 2 Address). I implemented table-per-class hierarchy for the inheritance. In my Address mapping I had: a foreign generator, 2 subclass tags, discriminator values and a one-to-one relationship to Envelope. But NHibernate complained about not liking the discriminator and the one-to-one together. So then I moved the one-to-one tag inside the subclass tags. Now NHibernate complained about not knowing what the Envelope property is ("Unable to resolve property: Envelope")

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your classes doe not comply with your tables. In envelope, remove the address fields. The adressFrom and addressTo variable will have (should have) a pointer to the envelope.

Comment: I do want to have a bi-directional relationship in my classes between Envelope and Address. The relationship is that Envelope has an Address From and an Address To, and that these addresses belong to Envelope. At best, I could live without the Envelope member variable from Address, but I cannot remove the FromAddress and ToAddress member variables from the Envelope class. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Are you using XML mappings OR mapping by code or Fluent?

Comment: I'm using XML mappings

Answer (score 0):

Surely an envelope should be a one-to-many with address?  That is an envelope can have many addresses (this will future proof your code if you have more than two addresses in the future)

However I am not sure why  you can't get the  [table-per-subclass](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass-discriminator) (using a discriminator) to work as you haven't posted your mappings. You do not need the bi-directional reference from address back to envelope as address inherits from envelope.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I need to model my classes after an existing database - whose schema I cannot change. Conceptually, an envelope has a from-address and a to-address. It doesn't have multiple addresses and I don't think this will change in the future. Address doesn't inherit from Envelope. Envelope 'has a' from-address and Envelope 'has a' to-address. It is not an inheritance relationship. I had to create 2 classes: FromAddress and ToAddress that inherit from Address just to make this work... and unfortunately I cannot. I'm getting: "Unable to resolve property: Envelope" at save time

Comment: Here's my code:
[link](http://pastebin.com/w2XPDdgb)
and
[link](http://pastebin.com/8wVkzygR)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with hibernate, but I recognize the problem, so I might put you on the right track, hoping an expert will further explain. It looks as if you have to predefine the envelop in the definition of address, this is a common error while programming, so I hope this helps.